# Paste first row/header row from main sheet to specific worksheets in workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook with eight (8) worksheets.  I would like to copy the header row (first row) from the main/principal worksheet and paste on the first row of certain spreadsheets (not all).

"Tax Bill Detail" = Main spreadsheet   [this is sheet1]

"Property Info" = worksheet to exclude [this is sheet2]

"Yardi Props Not on Tax Bill" = worksheet to exclude [this is sheet7]

"CSV" = worksheet to exclude [this is sheet8]

The code below is what I have so far.  Is there a more efficient way of writing this code?

```
Dim ws As Worksheet

Tax.Range("1:1").Copy

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.name <> "Tax Bill Detail" And ws.name <> "Property Info" And ws.name <> "Yardi Props Not on Tax Bill" And ws.name <> "CSV" Then
    ws.Range("1:1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably a tiny bit more efficient, and also easier to read/comprehend:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet

Tax.Range("1:1").Copy

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

    Select Case ws.Name
        Case "Tax Bill Detail", "Property Info", "Yardi Props Not on Tax Bill", "CSV"
            'DO NOTHING FOR THESE SHEETS
        Case Else
            ws.Range("1:1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    End Select
Next
```

Comment: Great!  This does make it easier to comprehend and it works a little more efficiently.  I don't have the rep yet to up-vote.

Comment: You're welcome! No need to upvote -- you've already accepted the answer and I have enough reputation points as it is :)